# Spring Boot - 2 log files created

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot

I've setup my spring boot application to write a log file to `/data/log/spring.log`. This log file is generated and written to but the standard log file at `/var/log/spring.log` is also generated and written. Basically I've duplicate log files in different places. Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: Show your logging configuration, is it the standard spring logging? is it an external logging framework? did you use the application.properties file?

Comment: The only configuration for logging that I'm using is the logging.file line in the application.properties file. logging.file=/data/log/spring.log